# Mathematica package to calculate the graph crossing number

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages, algorithm

I have been searching for a mathematica package that can calculate the [graph Crossing number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_(graph_theory)) of a (small) given arbitrary graph (the graphdata of known graphs doesn't help me).  Before I write my own I'm checking here.  My google searches returned methods to calculate it (or variants of the question) but didn't find any real implementation.

Comment: I once did a search for this, and could not find anything. Note that this is a hard problem and likely only feasible for tiny graphs! There's a Mathematica Journal article, but it only discusses a few special cases. https://www.mathematica-journal.com/2009/11/crossing-number-graphs/  `GraphData` does not implement any algorithm for this, it's only a database of pre-computed properties. If your graph of interest is not in it, you're out of luck.

Comment: IGraph/M has the `IGSmoothen` function which you may find useful: it eliminates all degree-2 vertices, creating a smaller graph with the same crossing number.  [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) has a (very inefficient) crossing number implementation. You may look for inspiration in the discussion around that: https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/24216  Finally, if you do implement something yourself, consider contributing it to IGraph/M.

Comment: @Szabolcs When I read some progress of crossing number. I found such an online tool, which seems to be great, but I am not very good at using it. http://crossings.uos.de/

Answer (score 4):

Geoffrey Exoo wrote code for finding (rectilinear) crossing numbers of arbitrary (small enough) graphs.  I asked him last year about the possibility of reviving it from whatever retired hardware (floppies) it lives on.  Unfortunately, I gather any such efforts have not (yet?) been successful.

Comment: For such hard problems, the most fruitful approach is often to map them into integer programming. There are multiple papers on how to do this for crossing numbers and Mathematica already has a good ILP solver. Have you looked into this?  (BTW the same approach worked *very* well for graph colouring—map it into SAT and solve using Mathematica. Did you get my MathWorld feedback email on this?)

Comment: I'd love to see this implemented in M: http://ls11-www.cs.tu-dortmund.de/people/chimani/files/oocm-preprint.pdf If anyone succeeds, please contact me.

Answer (score 3):

There are some C or Java programs available for computing crossing number, but not in wolfram language. But we can call it. One of them is [QuickCross](https://sites.flinders.edu.au/flinders-hamiltonian-cycle-project/quickcross-crossing-number-problem/).

```
Import["!D://QuickCross//QC -g I~qkzXZLw", "Table"]
                      (*{{"CR", ":", 12}}*)
```

This is a bit like *Mathematica* calling nauty-geng's results.

If one wishes to actually solve instances, Markus Chimani and Tilo Wiedera
produced a mixed-integer linear program in 2016 that is able to compute crossing numbers for small graphs, complete with a proof file, and produced an online interface, [Crossing Number Web Compute](http://crossings.uos.de/) , where researchers can submit their owninstances.

The crossing number results of specific graphs can be referred to in the following review.

- Clancy K, Haythorpe M, Newcombe A. A survey of graphs with known or
  bounded crossing numbers[J]. arXiv preprint arXiv:1901.05155, 2019.